# SQLite Duplicates NULL Perl

Tags: sqlite, perl

I use the following code in Perl to find duplicates in my SQLite database on the basis of 5 columns (Term1 to Term5).

```
my $dublette = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("
SELECT t.ID, t.Tag1, t.Tag2, t.Term1, t.Term2, t.Term3, t.Term4, t.Term5 
FROM Data t inner join (
SELECT ID, Tag1, Tag2, Term1, Term2, Term3, Term4, Term5, COUNT(*) c FROM Data GROUP BY Term1, Term2, Term3, Term4, Term5 HAVING c > 1) 
x on t.Term1=x.Term1 AND t.Term2=x.Term2 AND t.Term3=x.Term3 AND t.Term4=x.Term4 AND t.Term5=x.Term5
```

This seems to work exept if my unused values are NULL (but it works if they are empty). Any idea ho can I change it to get all duplicates?

Comment: Comparing to NULL is always false when using `=`. Using `IS`, however, will be true if both expressions are NULL.

Comment: Oh. That simple. Thank you. It works.